# web.config rewrite sub sub directory URL

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, windows-server

I have trouble use rewire my site URL, here's my site structure:

```
index.html
name-folder(folder)
name.html
   name2.html
   name3.html
     second-folder(folder)
     second.html
       second2.html
       second2.html
```

because the folder name and page.html same are the same, the server won't render the page if I don't change the folder name.

but my client wants the URL the same like before, so I tried to use web.config to rewrite URL rules, got the first directory work, but second
subdirectory still not working.

example:
[www.yourdomain.com/name-folder/name2](http://www.yourdomain.com/name-folder/name2)
[www.yourdomain.com/name/name2](http://www.yourdomain.com/name/name2)  (<---this work)

for the sub sub-directory
[www.yourdomain.com/name-folder/second-folder/second](http://www.yourdomain.com/name-folder/second-folder/second) (this is regular URL)
[www.yourdomain.com/name-folder/second/second2](http://www.yourdomain.com/name-folder/second/second2) (<--when I remove the second "-folder" name on the URL work, but if I remove first "-folder" won't work)

```
www.yourdomain.com/name/second/second2 (<---that's what I need, but it's not working currently.)
```

**I need to remove all the folder have "-folder" name on it for match old URL.**

Here's my web.config I tried to remove sub sub-directory folder name rewrite:

```
<!-- remove "-folder"in the child directory URL -->
<rule name="removesubfoldername" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)" negate="false" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
<add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="\/{R:1}-folder\/{R:1}-folder\{R:2}" />
</rule>
<!--         end of re-write folder name -->
```

Comment: could you... share the folder structure for reference?

Comment: @BagusTesa sorry about that, just update my post, thank you so much for the helping me.

Comment: sorry for letting you down, i can't manage to find the solution as IIS Url Rewrite will only executes the `<rule>` once on one request (perhaps to avoid rewrite loop that you can find on Apache webserver) and it cant process nesting [capture group](https://regex101.com/r/J38jFg/1). i hope someone else can help you. sorry..

Comment: btw, i just realised, since you had `name1.html` that represent `name` why dont you put it as an `index.html` inside the `name` folder? that also for the `second.html`..

Comment: @Bagus Tesa thank you so much for your comment, the structure is follow by their old site, and they want to keep same way. Someone help me out with this, I will share it later I’m here. I’m really appreciate your help!!! You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working web.config which successfully removed the "-folder" name from my folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="extensionless" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)\.html$" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="removeextension" enabled="true">
        <match url=".*" negate="false" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html" />
    </rule>
<!-- remove sub sub "-folder"in the child directory URL -->
    <rule name="removesubfoldername" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)" negate="false" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}-folder\/{R:2}-folder\/{R:3}" />
     </rule>
     <!--         end of re-write folder name -->
<!-- remove "-folder"in the child directory URL -->
    <rule name="removefoldername" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)\/(.*)" negate="false" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}-folder\/{R:2}" />
    </rule>

<!--         end of re-write folder name -->
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @pang That's the working web.config help me successful remove folder name, sorry about the confusion.